# How to get sum of unique names while grouping by date

Tags: oracle

I am using oracle 10g and i have a table of logged in users

```
created                userid
--------------------   ------
10-jul-2014 10:10:10   usr1
10-jul-2014 10:12:10   usr2
10-jul-2014 11:12:10   usr1
10-jul-2014 12:12:10   usr3
13-jul-2014 10:12:10   usr1
13-jul-2014 11:12:10   usr2
```

The output i am looking for is

```
created            count(userid)
-----------        ------------------
10-jul-2014        3 (3 unique users)
13-jul-2014        2 (2 unique users)
```

Query i came up with is not working as expected

```
select trunc(created) cr, userid  
from loggedinusers
group by trunc(created), userid
order by trunc(created) asc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below query

```
select trunc(created) cr, count(distinct userid)
from loggedinusers 
group by trunc(created)
order by trunc(created) asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select trunc(created) cr, count(userid) as cnt
from loggedinusers   
group by trunc(created)
order by trunc(created) asc;
```